# When query return are empty, all index's candidatePlanScores are similar, MongoDB can't choose a useful Index to same query shape's query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I am using 4.2.6 have a 1E doc collection , when my query return 0 ( empty match ), all of the Indexes's `candidatePlanScore`s in plan cache are similar , it let MongoDB random to use index , and then a query will return data , the query will become slow query.

[image]

I have seen a parameter `internalQueryCacheReplanningEnabled` seems to be able to solve this problem ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15225 ) , but 4.2.6 didn't see this parameter , is there any solution to let MongoDB choose a faster index , thank you!

the following is my query and the indexes which build for the statement :
statement :

```
db.Wager.aggregate([{ $match: { CompanyId: 1341,  WDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-03-01T04:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2024-04-26T21:00:00.791Z") },BDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-16T21:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2021-04-26T21:00:00Z") },  UDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-26T20:50:00Z") } } },  { $group: { _id: 1, n: { $sum: 1 } } }])
```

Indexes :

```
{ "CompanyId" : -1,"UDateUtc" : -1,"WDateUtc" : -1},
{ "CompanyId" : 1,BDateUtc:-1,"WDateUtc" : -1,"UDateUtc" : -1}
```

Comment: You can try index hints.

Comment: HI @D.SM ,in production the hint will be final answer , I know hint and index filter can be helpful , we wants fundamentally solve this problem.thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question myself,I used aggregate to count , but when my return are empty , MongoDB doesn't know which index should be used .

There is my solution , I add $project between $match and $group , it make MongoDB know which statement I was used , the following is my change .

db.Wager.aggregate([{ $match: { CompanyId: 1341,  WDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-03-01T04:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2024-04-26T21:00:00.791Z") },BDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-16T21:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2021-04-26T21:00:00Z") },  UDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-26T20:50:00Z") } } },  { $group: { _id: 1, n: { $sum: 1 } } }])

become

db.Wager.aggregate([{ $match: { CompanyId: 1341,  WDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-03-01T04:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2024-04-26T21:00:00.791Z") },BDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-16T21:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2021-04-26T21:00:00Z") },  UDateUtc: { $gte: ISODate("2021-04-26T20:50:00Z") } } },{$project:{CompanyId: 1,WDateUtc: 1,BDateUtc: 1,UDateUtc: 1,_id: 0}},{ $group: { _id: 1, n: { $sum: 1 } } }])

Careful , the _id must be 0 ,otherwise the plan cache maybe same as before add $project.

thank for watch